# historical weather data from python noaa_sdk api and generator?

Tags: python, api, weather, noaa

I am trying to get historical weather data using the python [noaa_sdk](https://github.com/paulokuong/noaa) for the noaa api.  I am using the following code from an example:

```
from noaa_sdk import noaa

n = noaa.NOAA()
observations = n.get_observations('08205','US', start='2017-07-04', end='2018-07-06')
for observation in observations:
    print(observation)
    break
```

But when I do and include the start and end dates, I don't get a 'print(observation)' response.

I think it has to do with the generator and yield in the get_observations() function but I can't figure it out.  If I don't put in the start and end dates, it works...any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for letting me know. Please use the latest version 0.1.14.
In the future, please go to:
https://github.com/paulokuong/noaa/issues
adding issue.

It is due to the inconsistent structure of the json response from NOAA.
thanks again.

Comment: Thank you, I upgraded and don't get the error now, but it also doesn't print the data...  Could you provide an example where you are pulling historical data over a range?  I think this is where the generator/yield might be tripping me up...

Comment: I am having that issue . Adding dates with no error but no values are printing. Were you able to find a solution?